# How can I change the color of check mark \u2713 in html.erb file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on Ruby on Rails and using Bootstrap.

```
<td>
    <% if textbook.offer == true %>
      <%= "\u2713" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= "\u2715" %>
    <%end%>
</td>
```

How can I change "\u2713" color into red

Comment: did your try .hex method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give it a class and use css to change the color.

```
<span class="tick"><%= "\u2713" %></span>
```

In your css file

```
.tick{
  color: red;
}
```